404 not found on app httpProxyMiddleware Nextjs
I am sending an api request to linkedin via the nextjs client but reached a cors access error and found I had to proxy the request via the nextjs server. I'm struggling to setup the proxy becuase I keep getting a 404 not found on the resource path (app router). I am on the latest version of nextjs
I have a route file in ./src/app/api/proxy/[...all].ts with the following content
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import httpProxyMiddleware  from 'next-http-proxy-middleware';

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) =>
  httpProxyMiddleware(req, res, {
    // Target API that we want to proxy the requests to
    target: 'https://api.linkedin.com',

    // Optionally rewrite the path. We can remove the '/api/proxy' part.
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api/proxy/linkedin': '', // Removes /api/proxy/linkedin from the URL, leaving just /v2/me
    },

    // Enable change of origin for the proxy
    changeOrigin: true,
  });

http://localhost:3000/api/proxy/linkedin/v2/me 404 (Not Found)
, I am trying to redirect a request from my client
       const response = await axios.get("/api/proxy/linkedin/v2/me", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user?.oAuthAccessToken}`,
        },
      }); 

I am expecting a 200 OK or 401 Invalid access token against the linkedin api however I'm unable to reach the api endpoint as its not hitting the proxy.
, I want to map http://localhost:3000/api/proxy/linkedin/v2/me to http://linkedin/v2/me , is there something wrong in my setup?
If someone is able to point my in the right direction I'd truly be greatful, my nextjs skills are very rusty.
